# Is $\{\varnothing \}$ an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Is $\{\varnothing \}$ an empty set ?**
this suppose  to be 7th grade math ,i went through the empty set lesson in the textbook , basically i know that

**{} or $\varnothing$ is an empty set**

but what about **$\{\varnothing\}$** which is  a question in the textbook , i was thinking

> what if $\varnothing$ is a symbol in $\{\varnothing\}$

but again im not sure . i'll appreciate any help . thanks for advance.

Comment: Think of it like this: a box that contains an empty box isn't empty, is it?

Comment: that is a very good hint ! wow! thank you so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that whatever $x$ is, $x\in\{x\}$.

Comment: i edited the question  , so it wont change the answer that its not an empty set right ?

Comment: My hint still applies. Now pick $x=\varnothing$ instead of $x=\phi$.

Comment: just wanted to make sure :P . thank you so much again , you have no idea how it was helpful !i understand it now.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

one denotes the empty set by $\emptyset$ or $\{ \}$.

The set $\{\phi\}$ is not empty as it contains an element, namely $\phi$.

Note the difference between the LaTeX symbols: $\phi$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: the symbol that im asking for is phi , which would be the empty set notation if its alone :) thank you .

Comment: @Bswan usually one uses $\emptyset$ or $\varnothing$ (the latter being my preferred choice) rather than the letter $\phi$ which is not standard for the empty set, they just look similar on paper.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is only *one* empty set.  It is the *only* set which has no elements.  Thus, it is not meaningful (and a sign that you haven't fully grasped the concept yet) if you talk about **an** empty set in your question.

$\emptyset$ and $\{\}$ are only two different symbolic representations for the *same* thing - like e.g. "$4$" and the Roman numeral "IV" are two different representations for the same number.

Comment: i think i got it , i only had adoubt about it. thank you :)